# Unable to create Entity Data Model Connecting to Oracle

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, visual-studio, entity-framework

I'm trying to introduce Entity Framework into my .NET project with an existing Oracle database. I've gone through the steps of setting installing the ODAC tools and Visual Studio Extensions. I've created the connection in Visual Studio and in the Web.config file. But when I try and create the Entity Data Model, the connection does not appear. And when I click to add a new connection there is no option for Oracle as a data source. I've also added the Oracle ManageData Nuget packages. I thought it was because I was using VS 2019. But it's not working in 2017 either.

I followed the guide here, https://www.oracle.com/tools/technologies/quickstart-visual-studio.html

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should change the .NET Framework from 4.5 to 4.6. (From what I have read, 4.52 is the minimum that will work with the EF 6 / Oracle setup.) Then, installed several NuGet packages: (just type oracle)

1. Official Oracle ODP.NET, Managed Driver
2. Official Oracle ODP.NET, Managed Entity Framework Driver
3. Oracle Data Provider for .NET (ODP.NET) Managed Driver
4. Oracle Rdb Entity Framework Provider

Finally, closed and reopened Visual Studio, and reopened the solution. Now, when adding a Model you will see Oracle options in the Data Source list!

Hope to useful to you, my friend :))

[image]

Comment: @AntarrByrd: I'm using VS 2017. I will try to install VS 2019 on tomorrow and inform you later. If you're Ok, we can communicate via skype, my friend :d